# Is there a better way to include CSS files installed by npm?

Tags: css, vue.js, dependencies, quill

I'm using the Quill WYSIWYG editor in a Vue project that I'm working on.

I've installed quill via `npm install quill@1.3.6`. Files are installed to `node_modules/quill/`.

When importing the JavaScript I do `import Quill from 'quill'` in the component that needs it, but in order to include the CSS I have a section in my Vue component like this:

```
<style scoped>
    @import '../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css'
</style>
```

This works fine for me - but I'm not sure that this is the best way to include these files/if there is a better way. Is there a better way? I wasn't sure if accessing them through the `node_modules` directory is the "professional" way to do this or if there are any issues with this approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct approach, however you can usually omit `node_modules` from the path because Webpack will search this path by default (unless you have configured it otherwise):

```vue
<style scoped>
    @import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'
</style>
```

Alternatively you can import the CSS in JavaScript code like you would any other module:

```vue
<script>
    import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'
</script>
```

If you import it this way, then you can be sure that the CSS will be bundled only once, whereas I don't think importing it in CSS will de-dupe the styles if you import it in multiple CSS files in your project (but in your use-case this may not be an issue).